# Finding the dimension of a matrix. (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the dimension of the vector space of $5$ x $5$ matrices $A$ satisfying the equation $A+A^{T}=I$

What I tried:

I started by using a simple $2$ by $2$ matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  -3\\
3  &  1\\
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  3\\
-3  &  1\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  0\\
0  &  2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The sum is thus an identity matrix  hence $A$ in this case would have a dimension $2$ extending it to a matrix of higher dimension. I notice a similar pattern and thus I conclude that the matrix $A$ has a dimension of five. Am I correct? Could anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: Why is it a vector space? If it was, then it should be closed under addition of matrices. If it is not empty, then there's some $A$ for which $A + A^T = A^T + (A^T)^T = I$, so $A$ and $A^T$ are elements of the vector space. Then, their sum $I$ should be as well. But $I + I^T = 2I \neq I$.

Comment: your set is not a vectorspace, since if $A$ and $B$ are there, their sum $A+B$ is not

Comment: Are you looking to the **affine space**?

Comment: Even more to the point $0$ (the zero-matrix) is not in our set, since $0 + 0^T = 0 + 0 = 0 \neq I$.

Comment: Do you want the dimension of the subspace of $M_5(\mathbb{R})$ spanned by the matrices $A$ such that $A+A^T=I$ ?

Comment: Yup thats what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If, you want the dimension of the subspace of $M_5(\mathbb{R})$ spanned by the matrices $A$ such that $A+A^T=I$ note that the matrix $A$ has the form
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}I+B
$$
where $B$ is  antisymmetric matrix.

Since antisymmetric matrices form a vector space, the span of the matrices $A$ is the space of all matrices of the form $A'=aI+B$.

Now find a basis for the subspace of antisymmetric matrices (can you do this?) and you have your answer.